# Single set in a topology

Tags: general-topology

What is meant by a single set in a topological space? The statement goes as: "let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T'}$ respectively".

Comment: I think it is meant as "$X$ and $X'$ are two topological spaces having the same underlying set".

Comment: Right, I think they mean for example that $X$ and $X'$ are, say, the unit interval in the reals with the usual and discrete topologies, respectively. Perhaps I would have worded it more clearly, it's a little confusing.

Comment: Ok,so by a "single set" what is meant is the same set but with two different topologies.. thanks!

Comment: Where did you see the term? Say if it is a book, then just check the word within the book :).

Comment: It is sometimes used to mean that the two topologies contain the same set, which is called $X$ when considered a member of $T$ and $X'$ when considered a member of $T'$.  If memory serves, Munkres does that, but I don't have my copy of his intro to topology handy to check and I may be wrong.

Comment: I found it in Munkres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here means,for example,a $\mathbf{one}$ set,say, $X_{0}$ endowed with two different topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$, because in views of their different topologies,a $\mathbf{single}$ set $X_{0}$ could be two different topological spaces, namely $X$ and $X'$ respectively.But as sets,$X=X'$.